# How to hide title bar in full screen mode for Excel 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba, window, title

Currently we have some reports in Excel that we use as dashboards for TV screens in various departments. We set these to full screen mode to hide ribbons etc, but the title bar at the very top still shows. I have some code I can use to hide this, but it only works for 32 bit Excel. I need this to work for 64 bit as well (or instead).

The code I have been using for 32 bit is as below.

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal bRevert As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPosition As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetFocus Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndLock As Long) As Long


Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16) '// The offset of a window's style
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE As Long = (-20) '// The offset of a window's extended style
Private Const WS_CAPTION As Long = &HC00000 '// Title bar bit
Private Const WS_SYSMENU As Long = &H80000 '// System menu bit
Private Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000 '// Sizable frame bit
Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Long = &H20000 '// Minimize box bit
Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Long = &H10000 '// Maximize box bit
Private Const WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW As Long = &H80 '// Tool Window: small titlebar bit
Private Const SC_CLOSE As Long = &HF060 'Constant to identify the Close menu item
'// Set or clear a bit from a style flag
Private Sub SetBit(ByRef lStyle As Long, ByVal lBit As Long, ByVal bOn As Boolean)


If bOn Then
lStyle = lStyle Or lBit
Else
lStyle = lStyle And Not lBit
End If


End Sub
Public Sub SetStyleHide()


Dim lStyle As Long, hMenu As Long

'Get the basic window style
lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hwnd, GWL_STYLE)


If lStyle = 0 Then
MsgBox "Unable to determine application window handle...", vbExclamation, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If


'// Build up the basic window style flags for the form adapted to the application window not UF's


SetBit lStyle, WS_CAPTION, False
SetBit lStyle, WS_SYSMENU, False
SetBit lStyle, WS_THICKFRAME, False
SetBit lStyle, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, False
SetBit lStyle, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, False


'Set the basic window styles
SetWindowLong Application.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle


'Get the extended window style
lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)

'// Handle the close button
'// hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hWnd, 1)


'// Not wanted - delete it from the control menu
hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hwnd, 0)
DeleteMenu hMenu, SC_CLOSE, 0&

'Update the window with the changes
DrawMenuBar Application.hwnd
SetFocus Application.hwnd


End Sub


Public Sub SetStyleShow()


Dim lStyle As Long, hMenu As Long

'Get the basic window style
lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hwnd, GWL_STYLE)

If lStyle = 0 Then
MsgBox "Unable to determine application window handle...", vbExclamation, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If


'// Build up the basic window style flags for the form adapted to the application window not UF's


SetBit lStyle, WS_CAPTION, True
SetBit lStyle, WS_SYSMENU, True
SetBit lStyle, WS_THICKFRAME, True
SetBit lStyle, WS_MINIMIZEBOX, True
SetBit lStyle, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, True


'Set the basic window styles
SetWindowLong Application.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle


'Get the extended window style
lStyle = GetWindowLong(Application.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)

'// Handle the close button
'// hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hWnd, 1)


'// Not wanted - delete it from the control menu
'hMenu = GetSystemMenu(Application.hwnd, 0)
'DeleteMenu hMenu, SC_CLOSE, 0&

'Update the window with the changes
DrawMenuBar Application.hwnd
SetFocus Application.hwnd


End Sub
```

This works fine for 32 bit, but errors if I run it on a 64 bit version. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You need to turn your longs to longlong or longptr and declare your functions as ptrsafe
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview

Comment: Here: [Win32API_PtrSafe](http://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt) is a good resource to find the 64 bit declarations of the Win32API.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to both of you for your help. Amending longs to longptr and declaring as ptrsafe worked perfectly.

Comment: @krabople Please not that not **all** `Long` automatically become `LongPtr`! While `PtrSafe` is always needed, there are cases where a `Long` stays a `Long`. Therefore always have a look into the list I linked or google for the correct `PtrSafe` version of the declaration. Just changing all `Long` to `LongPtr` will make you run into issues soon or later! • For example it must be `nIndex As Long` and doesn't change to `LongPtr`.